# Select dropdown value based on value in DB

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular JS. I have a dropdown box where static options with values are present.
Based on condition I have to select the default value which matches the value from Database. How can it be achieved?
model="TemplateObj.IsActive" has the int value 0,1 or 2 from DataBase.

```html
  <label class="">STATUS</label>
<select class="form-control input-sm" style="border: none" required ng-model="TemplateObj.IsActive" >
 <option value="2">In Development</option>
 <option value="1">Active</option>
 <option value="0">InActive</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [**ngOptions**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) instead of normal `HTML select`.

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    
    $scope.status = [{
        title: 'In Development',
        value: 2
    }, {
        title: 'Active',
        value: 1
    }, {
        title: 'Inactive',
        value: 0
    }];
    
    $scope.TemplateObj = {
     "IsActive": 1
    } 
    
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-model="TemplateObj.IsActive" ng-options="option.value as option.title for option in status"></select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-options` directive with array of statuses. The syntax may look a bit complicated for beginner, but you'll learn it someday: `value as title for element in array`

JS:

```
$scope.statuses = [{
    title: 'In Development',
  value: 2
}, {
    title: 'Active',
  value: 1
}, {
    title: 'Inactive',
  value: 0
}];
```

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="TemplateObj.IsActive" ng-options="status.value as status.title for status in statuses"></select>
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thesameson/r0xkc57c/) with working example.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to make use of the **ng-options** directive.

The documentation is [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) and there are quite a few examples you can guide from.